# Center-align one element while right-aligning its only sibling using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve this using flexbox:

[image]

I know how to do it by using a hidden element [as in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsf34gL5/1/):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.box:first-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

But this seems like too hacky to be right.

Comment: Why don't you try Grid?

Comment: @ManojKumar the OP isn't asking a solution using the grid, and the link to duplicate give a solution for a grid, not using flex.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph But there is one answer with these methods: https://prnt.sc/owtkl9 I just suggested him to use Grid, not that I am making him to discontinue flex.

Comment: I agree that grid is the best option here, but the other post does not deliver a solution even with the method in the screenshot. It says about vertical alignment and the OP is asking for horizontal.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph How is this vertical? https://prnt.sc/owtthv

Comment: @ManojKumar please try running code snippet for `Method #4: Add flex: 1 to left and right items`

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Ok then OP must work with the first solution of positioning which is only possible other than the invisible elements. Should I reopen it even now?

Comment: @ManojKumar the question is a perfect duplicate since all the possible ways are listed there. If someone know another way, he should add it to the duplicate.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for the confirmation. For a moment, I thought I forgot the meaning of vertical and horizontal.

Comment: My question is absolutely not a perfect duplicate as the linked question asks about how to accomplish this with *four* elements and I am asking about how to accomplish it with *two* elements and one of the solutions (method #4) in that question doesn't work when there are only two elements! For this to be a perfect duplicate I should be able to use that answers as-is which is not possible. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and found a better solution to the problem by using a CSS grid.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  /*
   * Create 3 columns grid (1 ghost grid column)
   * Make first/left (ghost) and last/right column streched and center one auto width
  */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.center {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  /* start your center child from 2nd column */
}

.right {
  /* Do your content right align */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="box">Center</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="box">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `flex` property that sets the flexible length on flexible items. That way, I'm telling the `white-box` to take all available space but the first `white-box` will be 50% larger than the normal `white -box`, that will take the place of what's left

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.white-box {
  background: white;
  flex: 1;
}

.white-box:first-child {
 flex: 1.5
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="white-box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="white-box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When viewing it in full screen, does that look centered?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily achieve this kind of layout by using CSS grid

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 100px 200px 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.grid-container > div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="red">2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div class="red">4</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove

```
.box:first-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```